# Does Kant's concept of 'representations' advocate for any agency as a function of the mind?

Tags: epistemology, kant, self-cognition

Kant never seems to define his usage of the concept of 'representations'. Nevertheless it appears to play a central role in his depiction of the mind's cognitive capability. When he says that 'that objects make representations to the mind', in what sense is he using the verb 'make'? [see excerpt below]

A. B. Dickerson
Kant on Representation and Objectivity

A. B. Dickerson, Kant on Representation and Objectivity, Cambridge University Press, 2004, 217pp, $60 (hbk), ISBN 0521831210

Reviewed by 
Robert Howell, State University of New York, Albany

Kant’s Transcendental Deduction of the Categories, in the Critique of Pure Reason, justifies the objective validity of those fundamental a priori concepts. Dickerson offers a novel exegesis of the Critique’s second- (B-) edition version of the Deduction, the clearest development of Kant’s reasoning. Dickerson’s work should interest everyone concerned with the details of this, the central argument of the critical philosophy.

For Dickerson, Kant is a representationalist. Representations are the immediate objects of our awareness. However, we cognize objects like trees neither by inferring those objects as the causes of representations nor by constructing them out of representations. Rather, via what Kant calls apperception we are made aware of the object cognized “in” the representation, just as we see a face “in” the lines of a picture. That object is distinct from the matter of the representation, just as the face is distinct from the lines themselves. Moreover, the lines do not determine their own interpretation; we must apply a rule of projection in order to grasp them as representing the face. Similarly, representations as given (impressions and empirical concepts) do not determine their own interpretation.

For apperception to grasp a tree, an act of category-applying spontaneity is required (an act “not grounded upon the (passive) recognition of features of what is given in experience,” 37). This act is synthesis. In it, we apply a category-governed rule of projection and grasp the manifold as representing the tree. This application imposes an interpretation on our experience that our given experience does not ground. However, imposing this interpretation appears incompatible with the objectivity of cognition. The interpretation could be a fantasy; and even if we in fact use categories to interpret experience, what justifies that use as objective?

Hence the Deduction’s “basic aim”: to demonstrate that, and how, our categorial interpretation of experience can be not only spontaneous but also objective (44). To meet this objective, the Deduction analyzes the concept of cognizing an object. It shows that, given that we cognize an object “in” a representation, category application is required to interpret that representation. Moreover, that application is objective, for it is grounded “only upon essential facts about the cognizing mind” (56) in such a way that any possible cognizing mind would synthesize given intuitions in the same way. Thus, objectivity is reconciled with spontaneity.

Dickerson presents this interpretation in chapters 1 and 2, summarizing the overall B-Deduction argument thus (51):

**α.** All our cognition must involve a spontaneous synthesis. 
**ß.** If our cognition involves a spontaneous synthesis then this synthesis must be governed by the categories. 
**γ.** Therefore, the categories make our cognition possible.

My sense is that Kant, along with Leibniz and others, is performing mental acrobatics to avoid subscribing to Spinoza's positing of agency as a function within the individual human mind.

Comment: Firstly, I think it is a bit unfair to Kant if one was to evaluate his epistemology without considering his mature philosophy, especially the third critique. Also, the last paragraph sounds a bit like "science is about causation, but isn't that just mental acrobatics to state something about change that Aristotle wrote already" - it is comparing apples to oranges. I mean, 'agency' is just about as specific a term as representation or object.

Comment: Isn't "spontaneity" just another name for "agency"? Kant's reason and understanding are pretty active and even creative with what they do to the "manifold of sensibility", just what one would expect from an "agent". Kant's "objects" are not metaphysical objects, they are concrete appearances, intuitive unities brought under concepts. Presumably, the "making of representations" refers to this "bringing under" through schematism and categories of understanding. A peculiar version of what "agent intellect" used to do to metaphysical objects in Aristotle and Aquinas.

Comment: No, spontaneity is a reflex and can be unconscious. Agency involves conscious participation. Thanks for the elaboration of Kant's position. But it still seems as if the lengthening of the terminology string, like    'manifold of sensibility' and "bringing under" through schematism and categories of understanding",                                                        just seems to obfuscate, not to clarify the issue. I'm not sure that this helps, but it often seems that extra lengthening of concepts which should be able to be expressed definitively and simply just waters down the intention.

Comment: If all this wall of text comes down to the question whether *the process of perception*, for Kant, was *conscious and intentional*, then the answer clearly has to be "no". If it was about whether Kant thought there to be agency in some form involved, it would be more intricate, since spontaneity is all about agency in a certain sense. Both the power of judgement and productive imagination have an active part of sorts. Kant's epistemology is about how passive and active aspects can fit together without Leibnizian prestabilised harmony